# Apache 2.2 fails with "unable to write 'random state'" with 2048-bit RSA key (1024-bit works fine)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, mod-ssl

I'm usually pretty good with Apache and OpenSSL, but this one has me completely baffled. I'm running Apache 2.2.22 and OpenSSL 1.0.1 on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server. I have an IP-based virtual host configured, which redirects all HTTP requests to HTTPS and uses strict transport security to help keep it that way.

I'm migrating the site from a certificate issued by an internal CA to a certificate signed by StartSSL. The current certificate has a 1024-bit RSA key, the new one has a 2048-bit RSA key. The server has one or two other SSL vhosts, all of which use 1024-bit keys. The current certificate works perfectly.

The keys for both certificates are in the same directory, root-owned, and with `600` permissions (the directory is `710`). The certificates are both in a different directory, root-owned, and with `644` permissions (the directory has `755`). (E.g. both keys are in `/var/ssl/keys` and both certs are in `/var/ssl/certs`.)

However, when I change the configuration to use the new certificate (this is the **only** change, I don't update the hostname or anything else) Apache refuses to start, giving a "unable to write 'random state'" error. I've checked, and I don't have any (root-owned or otherwise) `.rnd` files hanging around. If I change back to the 1024-bit certificate, Apache starts perfectly and everything is normal.

I came across [this FAQ entry](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_faq.html#keysize), stating that Apache doesn't support 2048-bit keys, but I also came across [this blog post](http://livecipher.blogspot.com/2010/09/use-2048bit-server-certificate-with.html) stating that the FAQ entry must be old (many of the entries do seem rather ancient) as it works perfectly on Apache 2.2.11.

Can anyone suggest why Apache may be failing with the new certificate?

Comment: Are you running on a virtual machine? It may be entropy exhaustion. FAQs 1&2 under [user] seem to hint at this as well https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html

Comment: No, it's a physical server (old, and 32-bit, but physical). I tried adding `export RANDFILE=/var/run/apache2/.rnd$SUFFIX` to `/etc/apache2/envvars`, but this changed nothing (server still runs with original cert).

Comment: Rather embarrassingly, I think I've solved this problem; the, err, certificate didn't match the key (still not sure how _that_ happened). *facepalm*